# MySQL View and Select Query

Tags: mysql, view

We are having a View combining 4 tables and we don't have any inner queries or sub-queries in that view. Example: Saying View1 having the structure,

```
Create view View1 as Select X, Y, Z from table1 JOIN table2
```

When I run this query, "Select * from view1". It is taking 2 seconds to retrieve the data.

But, When I run the view structure, say

```
Select X, Y, Z from table1 JOIN table2
```

it takes only 0.02 to 0.04 seconds.

Both queries are running on the same data, but the view is taking more time. What could be the reason?

Is there any possible way to optimize the view performance?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can add necessary selected column in select statement.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod I think you misunderstood the question, both the view and Select statements are having same queries. But It is taking time for running as view, the same Select query doesn't have any lagging problem

Comment: What could be the reason? Read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html